# How can I launch ipython from shell, by running 'python ...'?

Tags: python, shell, command-line, python-3.x, ipython

I would like to add some commandline options to a python launch code in order to actually invoke an ipython shell. How do I do that?

Comment: Could you explain your *real* problem?  I mean, which actual problem is this hack supposed to solve?

Comment: I use an IDE that has a limited support for an interactive shell to run your scripts in (pycharm), and I would like to be able to run the scripts in a more interactive way, such as in IEP.

Comment: The fix should work in windows environments as well

Comment: Does your license cover upgrading to the newly released PyCharm 2? They've added IPython support: http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/whatsnew/index.html

Comment: It does, the support is only in the python 'console' and not when running scripts. Also, I was unable to find how to enable ipython instead of python...

Answer (score 76, accepted):

To start IPython shell directly in Python:

```
from IPython import embed

a = "I will be accessible in IPython shell!"

embed()
```

Or, to simply run it from command line:

```
$ python -c "from IPython import embed; embed()"
```

---

`embed` will use all local variables inside shell.

If you want to provide custom locals (variables accessible in shell) take a look at `IPython.terminal.embed.InteractiveShellEmbed`

Comment: I am no longer using that environment or OS even, but I think this would have worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

You can first install IPython for your specific version and then [start Python with module name](https://docs.python.org/3.7/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m), e.g.:

```bash
$ python3.7 -m pip install IPython
$ python3.7 -m IPython

Python 3.7.7 (default, Mar 10 2020, 17:25:08) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.13.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]:
```

So you can even have multiple Python versions installed and start an IPython interpreter for each version separately. A next step for convenience would be to alias the command, e.g. in `.bashrc`:

```bash
alias ipython3.7='python3.7 -m IPython'
```

Then you can easily start IPython for the specific version(s):

```bash
$ ipython3.7
 
Python 3.7.7 (default, Mar 10 2020, 17:25:08) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.13.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]:
```

See also https://github.com/ipython/ipython#development-and-instant-running.

**EDIT** for Python3.12: I had some issues, getting IPython installed under Python3.12 (from deadsnakes) this way. The underlying problem was that `pkgutil` does not know `ImpImporter`, which is deprecated, meaning that I had a broken pip installation for Python3.12. Thanks to `ensurepip`, the solution is simple: `python3.12 -m ensurepip --upgrade`. Then `python3.12 -m pip install IPython` should work.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe an option is just to embed `ipython` in your code like this

```
def some_function():
    some code

    import IPython
    IPython.embed()
```

When you run the function in some code it will launch and `ipython` terminal whose scope is the one of the function from where it was called.

Answer (score 4):

To do exactly what you asked for, i.e. add command line options to a `python` invocation to actually invoke IPython, you can do this:

```
python -c 'import subprocess; subprocess.call("ipython")'
```

I can't imagine, though, any circumstances where this would be useful.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this way any commands passed and script file will still run in python and not ipython, right?

Comment: @Shwouchk:  Your original question provided very little information -- this answer was the best guess I could give.  From the comments to your original question, I would think this solution won't help you, but how about just trying?

Comment: This actually fixed a related issue for me running ipython from an emacs prompt, which I couldn't otherwise get to correctly flush the output to the emacs buffer.

Answer (score 2):

It is not entirely clear what you mean by "a python launch code"; I assume this refers to the shell code you use to launch Python.

On Unix, you could use [`alias`](http://ss64.com/bash/alias.html) to substitute one command for another:

```
aix@aix:~$ alias python=ipython
aix@aix:~$ python
Enthought Python Distribution -- http://www.enthought.com

Python 2.7.1 |EPD 7.0-2 (64-bit)| (r271:86832, Nov 29 2010, 13:51:37) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.10.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object'. ?object also works, ?? prints more.

In [1]:
```

If this is not what you want, please clarify your question.

Comment: Also this doesn't always matches your python executable.
`alias ipython="python -c 'from IPython import embed; embed()'"`

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean something like `python C:\Python27\Scripts\ipython-script.py`